# Is it possible to use PWAS in Android TV?

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, android-tv, trusted-web-activity

I was looking into web frameworks that support TV's by market size. Android, WebOS, Taizen, Microsoft, Apple .. **

I am using Trusted Web Activity / [svgomg](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/svgomg-twa) to build PWA based apps for Android TV.

It looks like it is supported :
https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/svgomg-twa/issues/91

But I tried building apk/app for Android TV and got this error :

```
I/OpenGLRenderer: Davey! duration=1588ms; Flags=0, IntendedVsync=85294375864, Vsync=85294375864, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=85300204600, AnimationStart=85300236800, PerformTraversalsStart=85300260700, DrawStart=85300629400, SyncQueued=85300648400, SyncStart=85300758100, IssueDrawCommandsStart=85300807700, SwapBuffers=85301335900, FrameCompleted=86882937700, DequeueBufferDuration=208000, QueueBufferDuration=409000, 
W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@5470549
D/TWALauncherActivity: Using URL from Intent (https://xx/).
D/TWAProviderPicker: Found no TWA providers, using first browser: null
W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@2076314
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xea644960: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xea6c1550)
W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@d15ce5f
D/TWALauncherActivity: Using URL from Intent (https://xx/).
D/TWAProviderPicker: Found no TWA providers, using first browser: null
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xea644960: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xea6c1550)
W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@2adfb62
W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@5de11e5
D/TWALauncherActivity: Using URL from Intent (https://xx/).
D/TWAProviderPicker: Found no TWA providers, using first browser: null
W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@1b55ae0
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xea644960: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xea6c1550)
W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@40ec95b
```

What are the alternatives to build PWAs that work on TV OSs? Or, at least to use a PWA in an Android TV app, similar to svgomg-twa?

Comment: Your reading your issue link wrong, it points to a open ticket which means it is still outstanding/not available.

Comment: The `svgomg-twa` demo is deprecated. Check out https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/bubblewrap/ and https://github.com/GoogleChrome/android-browser-helper for updated utilities and demos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, the easiest way to use a Web App on Android TV is by using the [WebView](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview). Many PWA features are not supported by the WebView.

Youtube uses [Cobalt](https://cobalt.foo/) as the platform to run their app across different platforms. It only supports a subset of HTML, CSS and JavaScript, so it doesn't provide PWA support.

Trusted Web Activity is **not** currently supported on Android TV. There's an open feature request at http://crbug.com/1054737.

For those interested in Trusted Web Activity support for Android TV, I'd recommend going to that [issue](http://crbug.com/1054737) and starring the feature request, so the team will have a better idea of the demand and can prioritise.